# Groovy says a method that takes java.util.Map cannot take a HashMap or a LinkedHashMap

Tags: dictionary, groovy

Trying to call a method that expects just a Map (as defined in the function itself in the class) does not work when passing in a LinkedHashMap or a HashMap. Groovy states why: there is no signature of that method applicable for augment types either LinkedHashMap or HashMap and a possible solution is just Map. How is this possible, since both implement Map?

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static myMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[VALUE1:I am value 1.]]
Possible solutions: myMethod(java.util.Map)
```

Comment: Most likely it is complaining about being used as `static` method. The method should be non-static.

Comment: ... or if that code is not under your control, you need to instance it first.

Comment: Props to both commenters. That is exactly the issue. Completely missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question was comment-answered, I will answer it myself.

The complaint was about me using it as a static method, when it is actually not one.